calling multiple web apis built with dotnetcore on a single page returns error
i built a project with c# dotnetcore 6 web api which includes multiple api endpoints. whenever the frontend engineer tries calling more than 2 apis on the dashboard, 1 is successful and the other returns a cors error. how do i resolve the issue permanently from the backend. i've configured cors settings already and there is no error calling just 1 endpoint. the error occures when calling any 2 endpoints at the same on a page.
i have configured cors settings already. i want multiple api calls to be called successfully without returning cors errors for 1




How did you configure CORS? Can you show your Startup.cs or Program.cs?

set below cors policy: `builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
builder => builder
.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true) // Allow any host
.WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition")); // Add any exposed headers if needed
});
var app = builder.Build();
// Use CORS
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");`

@afaolek i've updated the question with screenshots of my configuration.

@JalpaPanchal i already updated the question with my configuration. i've configured cors already but the issue still persists.

@AbayomiOlowu could you please share actual code in text instead of sharing code screenshot that would be great.

so i finally resolved it using this line of code
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy", policy => policy
.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.WithExposedHeaders("*"));
});

so this is how i later resolved it. inside my Program.cs
i previously had this
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy", policy => policy
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod();
});

then i updated it to this
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy", policy => policy
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .WithExposedHeaders("*"));
});

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

and that was how i stopped having the cors error
